# How does lowering your thermostat save energy?

Tags: energy, efficient-energy-use

Say it is winter and the outside temperature is 0 degrees f.

I set my thermostat to 74 degrees.  When the temperature inside my home reaches 72 degrees, the furnace will kick on and warm the house to 74.

Now, if I set my thermostat to 68 degrees to save energy, when my house reaches 66 degrees, the furnace will kick on and warm the house to 68.

In both instances, the same amount of energy was expended to raise the temperature by 2 degrees.

So how is it that keeping your thermostat at 68 will save energy?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The rate at which your home loses heat is proportional to the difference of temperature between the inside and the outside. This is [Newton's law of cooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convective_heat_transfer#Newton.27s_law_of_cooling). Hence, a higher temperature home will lose heat faster.

This means that if your thermostat is set lower, the furnace will need to turn on less often.

Answer (score 23):

Firstly, the specific heat (more precisely the specific enthalpy) of humid air varies a bit with temperature, so going from 72 to 74 degrees F will take a bit more energy than going from 66 to 68 F.

However this effect is not very large compared to the effect of heat lost through the house's walls, floor, and roof to the colder outside environment.

To a good approximation, the heat lost through conduction is proportional to the change in temperature between inside and outside. The constant of proportionality depends on the roof/wall/floor material and any insulation.

Say it's 40 degrees F outside. The rate of heat loss will then be greater at an interior temperature of 72 F than at 66 F due to the larger change in temperature.

There is also heat loss due to radiation from the windows as well.

There is a NIST article [at this link](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/82/jresv82n2p97_a1b.pdf) that covers this in much greater detail.

Comment: It takes the same amount of energy (and furnace running time) to heat the house 2 degrees, whether $66-68$ or $72-74$.  It will take more time for the house to cool from $68-66$ than from $74-72$, so the furnace will come on less often.  That is where the energy savings comes from.

Comment: @Ross, that would be true for room air of zero relative humidity. But usually that's not the case, and for humid air, there is a slight difference in enthalpy required. Granted, this effect is negligible compared to the heat loss by conduction to the outside.

Comment: Yes, you mentioned that and said it didn't matter much, which I agree with.  I thought this added to the already good explanation by showing how the energy savings shows up.

Comment: As a limiting example, suppose that it's winter in Florida and the temperature outside is $68^\circ\mathrm F$. If you set your thermostat to $74^\circ\mathrm F$ then your furnace will run sometimes, but if you set your thermostat to $68^\circ\mathrm F$ the weather outside will keep your house warm and your furnace will never run.

Comment: @RossMillikan isn't the rate of heat loss greater while the house is in the 72-74 range? Wouldn't that mean the effective efficiency of the furnace is lower so would use more fuel?

Comment: @Trengot:  usually you would compute the efficiency of the furnace as heat added to the house divided by energy input.  You would ignore (in this calculation) the losses from the house.  You are correct that because the loss rate is (a little) higher, the furnace will run (a little) longer to heat the house by $2F$.  The furnace outputs its heat at a constant temperature, so its efficiency should be just about constant.  Yes, the cooler house will have a cooler input temperature to the furnace.  I don't know how that impacts efficiency.

Answer (score 5):

Forget about the furnace kicking in at 2 degrees below the preset or whatever. This is immaterial. The heat is not needed to produce this temperature rise, but rather to compensate heat loss with the surroundings, and thus **maintain** the temperature.

You can clearly see that higher temperature presets need a higher amount of heat to be maintained, because the higher the temperature difference with the outside, the larger the heat dissipation with the surroundings, and **that** is the heat the furnace will have to produce.

If you intuitively think maintaining some temperature requires the same amount of heat per unit time regardless of temperature value, just think how much heat you would need to maintain the **same** temperature as the surroundings (zero), then to maintain some higher temperature (more than zero).

Answer (score -2):

Even ignoring losses, the higher temperature will be more expensive because of the cost of getting to 72% in the first place.

Comment: This isn't necessarily so if the OP lives in a region with seasonal temperature fluctuations.  The house will be warmer than 72 in the summer and then cool below 72 during the fall.  If we assume that the OP is only interested in heating the house, then there would be no cost to getting it to the initial warm state.